# Burns for EML-1 to LLO

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, lagrangian-points, hohmann-transfer

Wikipedia gives 0.64 or 0.65 km/s for going from LLO to EML-1 or back. I would like to know what the delta v of the specific burns involved are, and if my initial calculations are close, I don't see how their number can be correct.

[Here is Wikipedia article about delta-v budget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget).

It's complicated because it's a full 3-body problem, so I'm left trying to approximate it with a simplified model in the Moon's sphere of influence. LLO I have taken to be at 110 km, at 1.629 km/s. I have 61,000 km for the distance from the Moon to the EML-1 (from the approximation $R \cdot \sqrt{\frac{m_1}{3 \cdot m_2}}$).

First burn, I consider getting into an orbit with apogee at 61,000 km, which is at the radius of EML-1. Perigee for the elliptical orbit would be 2.27 km/s, with the difference from LLO being 0.641 km/s, which is our first burn.

NOTE: the numbers here are wrong staring with 0.714 km/s; see my answer for details.

Second burn, I calculate the speed at apogee of that elliptical orbit to be 0.068. However, EML-1 is circling around the Moon, which I would calculate by:

$$\frac{2 \cdot \pi \cdot R}{30 \cdot 24 \cdot 60^{2}}$$

if R is the 61,000 km distance from the Moon. This gives 0.714 km/s. If the orbit is going in the "right" direction, then I subtract the apogee speed from this to get 0.641 km/s for the second burn.

If you added these, it's 1.355 km/s total, and both burns are of about equal magnitude. I don't think that's right. These calculations are probably correct for the equations I'm using, but I strongly suspect that the underlying assumptions are highly flawed. Perhaps Earth's gravity has a major effect in the mechanics? In other cases, the EML-1 and EML-2 points are touted as extremely low delta v points to reach, but these numbers would seem to somewhat undermine that, if the 0.641 km/s burn is going "out of the way". But I'm not sure.

Does anyone have any serious numbers for the transfer from LLO to EML-1?

Comment: EML-1 or EML-2?

Comment: My interest was in EML-1, the near-side of the moon. Similar statements might apply for EML-2? Since that point is further from Earth, it would probably follow that the circularizing burn upon arrival at the point would be greater, according to the approximation I used, but this can't possibly be right either. Other people are surely interested in EML-2, but my interest is in EML-1.

Comment: Your question title says EML-1 to LLO, but the very first sentence says LLO to EML-2. In the second to last paragraph you talk about both EML-1 and EML-2. Then at the end it's back to LLO to EML-1.

Comment: That was a pure error. I didn't previously notice that. Edited the incorrect occurrence.

Comment: FWIW, the mean distance from the centre of the Moon to EML-1 is ~58,000 km, but it varies between 54,000 km & almost 62,000 km. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnqjr.png & https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49269/16685

Answer (score 2):

I realized an error in the math in my question that is significant enough to leave as a formal answer. The error occurred here, and I'll point it out in bold.

> However, EML-1 is circling around the moon, which I would calculate by 2*pi()*R/(30*24*60^2), **if R is the 61,000 km distance from the moon. This gives 0.714 km/s**. If the orbit is going in the "right" direction, then I subtract the apogee speed from this to get 0.641 km/s for the second burn.

The distance from the center of the moon to EML-1 is about 61,000 km, but the calculation erroneously plugged in 322,000 km, which is the distance from EML-1 to the center of Earth. If you plug in the intended (and more logical) number, you come to the conclusion that EML-1 is moving at about 150 m/s relative to the moon.

This is a very low number, but reasonable considering the circumstances. EML-1 is much closer to the moon, so if we're considering moon-based SOI calculations, it'll be notably lower than Earth-based SOI calculations. It is, at 150 m/s versus 700 m/s.

If the orbit direction is the same as the rotation of EML-1 about the moon, then we subtract 150 m/s - 68 m/s = about **81 m/s** (rounding after the fact here) in order to get the burn necessary to match the velocity vector of EML-1 for a projectile in transfer from LLO. As km/s, that is 0.081, so it would add fairly marginally to a 0.6 km/s burn at a perigee at LLO altitude, for 0.681 km/s total. The altitude of LLO is also a fungible number which can account for the range given in the slide referenced in the other answer, in additional to a possibility of some marginal gravity drag at LLO departure as well.

Let me embellish on another detail that I blew through in the question. Should it be 150 - 68 or 150 + 68? What direction do LLO orbits typically go in (for planned space missions)? Probably in the direction of the moon's rotation. So let me go point-by-point:

- Sun rises in the East, so Earth rotates counter-clockwise if viewed from N. Hemisphere
- Moon orbits in same direction as the Earth rotates, so counter-clockwise
- Moon is tidally locked, so it rotates counter-clockwise as well
- EML-1 rotates counter-clockwise about the moon by similar statements

Thus, it should be subtracted, instead of added. Possibility still remains for a 0.13 km/s modification (increase) if the mission is retrograde in LLO, which is admittedly unlikely. That could be why the range goes from 0.6 km/s to 0.8 km/ in the referenced slide, although I find little reason to ever assume the higher number.

The validity of the approximation is still highly questionable. Perhaps this the number here is still a pretty good ballpark. On Hop's blog, several mentions are given to a approx 0.5 km/s burn to drop from EML-1 into an Earth grazing orbit (not so different from 0.7). That *should* be a 3-body problem, but you can find that the Earth SOI approximation is very acceptable as a ballpark estimation. If the moon-side follows the same pattern, then we would conclude that 80 m/s is relatively close to the true answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but it is a start. I think you may not be able to arrive at correct numbers for a full 3BP maneuver doing piecemeal transfer orbit calculation. Your arithmetic may not ever add up to the real values that way.

The value of 0.65km/s from a halo orbit around Earth-Moon L1 to LLO can be found on this slide from the ULA presentation "[Transportation Enabling a Robust Cislunar Space Economy](http://www.ulalaunch.com/uploads/docs/Published_Papers/Commercial_Space/2016_Cislunar.pdf)".

There is also *a lot* to read in Zazzera, Topputo, and Massari's "[Assessment of Mission Design Including Utilization of Libration Points and Weak Stability Boundaries](http://www.esa.int/gsp/ACT/doc/ARI/ARI%20Study%20Report/ACT-RPT-MAD-ARI-03-4103b-InterplanetaryHighways-Milano.pdf)" and Koon, Lo, Marsden and Ross’ (KoLoMaRo’s) ”[Dynamical Systems, the Three Body Problem, and Space Mission Design](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~koon/book/KoLoMaRo_DMissionBk.pdf)" as well.

Here is just one example of getting from LEO to the EML1 halo: Zanzottera, Mingotti, Castelli and Dellnitz's "[Earth-to-Halo Transfers in the Sun–Earth–Moon Scenario](http://www.few.vu.nl/~rci270/publications/PaperZMCD.pdf)"

**Bear in mind:** the ellipses (and for that matter the distances) in this slide are schematic only. Those are not what the orbits actually look like.

> [image]

I haven't found an independent source for L2, but but at least the article in the [Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20120426010349/http://www.futureinspaceoperations.com/papers/HumanOps_Beyond_LEO_11_2010.pdf) cited by Wikipedia seems to treat L1 and L2 as roughly equivalently difficult (or easy) to access. [Wikipedia's  tabular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget#Earth.E2.80.93Moon_space.E2.80.94high_thrust) for high thrust:

> [image]

...and low thrust:

> [image]

...are all in the 0.6 to 0.8 km/sec range.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped contextualize some. I can see how the network additions add up, and the slide shows clearly that they meant to use that number. I browsed through the pdfs, but I'm not hopeful about any of them giving the number I wanted (the delta v going from EML-1 to the transfer orbit). I do see, however, that the number of 0.64, 0.60 or 0.80 is almost exactly the escape velocity from the moon's SOI. The implication is that the burn to match EML-1 velocity when you get there is "essentially zero". I'm willing to accept that, but I still seek a more scientific confirmation.

Comment: Yep, like I say "This is not a complete answer, but it is a start" - I am hoping someone more familliar with this will chime in. @hopdavid 's blog - [including this entry](http://hopsblog-hop.blogspot.com/2015/05/eml2.html) linked in [this answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/14623/12102) has some interesting reading (so does [this one](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/4144/12102) as well).