# Nickname and citation for famous, historic three-body spacecraft trajectory design "manual"; something like "DoKaRoMo"?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mission-design, reference-request, halo-orbit, three-body

There is a heavily-cited work about the use of three-body orbits with four authors, I think some at NASA at the time. I know that I've cited this abbreviation in my own posts a few times, but I can't remember what it is now.

It is sometimes referred to by an eight letter nickname consisting of the first two letters of each author's family name. My best guess is "DoKaRoMo" but that doesn't seem to be it.

**Question:** What is the proper citation for this paper and it's oft-used nickname?

Comment: Two down votes for a reference-request? May reduce visibility of the excellent answer and reference to a historic and incredibly helpful tome of orbital mechanics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are likely looking for **"KoLoMaRo"**.

[http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~koon/book/KoLoMaRo_DMissionBk.pdf](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/%7Ekoon/book/KoLoMaRo_DMissionBk.pdf)

Wang Sang **Ko**on, Martin W. **Lo**, Jerrold E. **Ma**rsden and Shane D. **Ro**ss *"Dynamical Systems, the Three-Body Problem, and Space Mission Design"*

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much, this is of course it. Wow but it's book-length. Now I know what I'll be doing this weekend. I'm going to adjust the title a bit in order to maximize searchability/findability of your answer.

Comment: yes, searching this site for "KoLoMaRo" finds three other answers: [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30173/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18225/12102), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43568/12102) and one in Astronomy SE: [4](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/38359/7982)

Comment: @uhoh Well worth a read!